# C++ insert data to MySQL return error

Tags: c++, mysql

I modified a set of code from MySQL page to test input data into MySQL table 'list'. The program exits with the following error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sql::SQLException'
  what():  
Aborted
```

After I checked through the table, the data was successfully inserted somehow.
I modified this program to repeat inserting the data using a for loop but end up the loop exited after first iteration (program forced to exit during first insertion).

I also tried with hard-coded query, which worked in MySQL manually input, but still had the same issue.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Running test insert"  << endl;

        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("localhost", "dev", "1234");

        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("million");

        string data("abc1234567890");

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("INSERT INTO list VALUES('0','" +
            data + "','" + data +"','" + data + "','" + data + "','" +     data + "');");
        }
        // replace with your statement
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;

        cout << endl;

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

With this try{} catch

```
try{....}
catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
    cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;     
    cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
    cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
    cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;}
```

Output this error message

```
# ERR: SQLException in test.cpp(main) on line 54
# ERR:  (MySQL error code: 0, SQLState: 00000 )
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not forget to properly escape your values. What you've got here is one step away from a severe SQL injection bug. Be sure to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-prepared-statements.html) when adding data to your queries.

Comment: I recommend formatting your SQL query into a string before placing into the function.  This will allow you to use a debugger and examine the contents of the string before it is sent to the MySQL database.

Comment: I got the same problem, any updates? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `sql::SQLException` is thrown because the `executeQuery()` function is supposed to return a `sql::ResultSet` after the SQL query execution (e.g. SELECT statement). For SQL queries that does not return any DB selection (e.g. CREATE, UPDATE) there is another function `execute()`.

The original answer can be found here: [MySQL Query executes but throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903383/mysql-query-executes-but-throws-exception)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and come across this post.
So just for the records.
I did an

```
if (res) {
  doSomeThing();
}
```

after executing the statement
and the SQLException disappeared