# MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, access-denied

First let me mention that I've gone through many suggested questions and found no relevent answer. Here is what I'm doing.

I'm connected to my Amazon EC2 instance. I can login with MySQL root with this command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then I created a new user bill with host %

```
CREATE USER 'bill'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passpass';
```

Granted all the privileges to user bill:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'bill'@'%' with grant option;
```

Then I exit from root user and try to login with bill:

```
mysql -u bill -p
```

entered the correct password and got this error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I think that will log you on as 'bill'@'localhost' which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Did you [`FLUSH PRIVILEGES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html)?

Comment: Okay, I tried this without any success. Any other suggestion please.

Comment: What version of the server are you running? I've seen 5.1 behave oddly about this.

Comment: This happened to me while installing Magento and I made a much sillier mistake. Putting 'mysql -u magento -p magento' was prompting me for a password and instead of the default password I was putting the root password in.

Comment: make sure to add with grant option to the end of the grant line. Several of the answers below have this buried in their lengthy answers. This is the only thing wrong with what you were doing. Just wasted some time on this myself.

Comment: @Ali Why not accept one as an answer?

Comment: @authentictech unfortunately, none of the suggested solutions worked for me at the time this question was posted. Please see my own answer that helped me getting outa this situation. That is the reason I did not mark any of them as the answer. Probably I can mark the highest ranked response as answer.

Comment: Very dumb of me but I should still mention in case someone else also makes this mistake since the error code is the same. I did not create a user by the name "bill" (or whatever name) before running the command mysql -u bill -p

Comment: Creating a user other than root to access the database is more secure; and going further to limit their access to only one table is even one better. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Anyone else was using wrong combination of username and password ? :)

Comment: Just noted: I was failed to create user and password. Accoding to the error message, I searched and found this thread. Please check the username and password if you are the same as me.

Comment: wrong password also cause `1045` !!!

Answer (score 495, accepted):

You probably have an anonymous user `''@'localhost'` or `''@'127.0.0.1'`.

As per [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html):

> When multiple matches are possible, the server must determine which of
> them to use. It resolves this issue as follows: (...)
>
> - When a client attempts to connect, the server looks through the rows *[of table mysql.user]* in sorted order.
> - The server uses the first row that matches the client host name and user name.
>
> (...)
> The server uses sorting rules that order rows with **the most-specific Host values first**.
> Literal host names *[such as 'localhost']* and IP addresses are the most specific.

Therefore such an anonymous user would "mask" any other user like `'[any_username]'@'%'` when connecting from `localhost`.

`'bill'@'localhost'` does match `'bill'@'%'`, but would match (e.g.) `''@'localhost'` beforehands.

The recommended solution is to drop this anonymous user (this is usually a good thing to do anyways).

---

*Below edits are mostly irrelevant to the main question. These are only meant to answer some questions raised in other comments within this thread.*

**Edit 1**

Authenticating as `'bill'@'%'` through a socket.

```
    root@myhost:/home/mysql-5.5.16-linux2.6-x86_64# ./mysql -ubill -ppass --socket=/tmp/mysql-5.5.sock
    Welcome to the MySQL monitor (...)
    
    mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
    +------+-----------+
    | user | host      |
    +------+-----------+
    | bill | %         |
    | root | 127.0.0.1 |
    | root | ::1       |
    | root | localhost |
    +------+-----------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
    
    mysql> SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();
    +----------------+----------------+
    | USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
    +----------------+----------------+
    | bill@localhost | bill@%         |
    +----------------+----------------+
    1 row in set (0.02 sec)
    
    mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_networking';
    +-----------------+-------+
    | Variable_name   | Value |
    +-----------------+-------+
    | skip_networking | ON    |
    +-----------------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Edit 2**

Exact same setup, except I re-activated networking, and I now create an anonymous  user `''@'localhost'`.

```
    root@myhost:/home/mysql-5.5.16-linux2.6-x86_64# ./mysql
    Welcome to the MySQL monitor (...)
    
    mysql> CREATE USER ''@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'anotherpass';
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    
    mysql> Bye

    root@myhost:/home/mysql-5.5.16-linux2.6-x86_64# ./mysql -ubill -ppass \
        --socket=/tmp/mysql-5.5.sock
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    root@myhost:/home/mysql-5.5.16-linux2.6-x86_64# ./mysql -ubill -ppass \
        -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=TCP
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    root@myhost:/home/mysql-5.5.16-linux2.6-x86_64# ./mysql -ubill -ppass \
        -hlocalhost --protocol=TCP
    ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

**Edit 3**

Same situation as in edit 2, now providing the anonymous user's password.

```
    root@myhost:/home/mysql-5.5.16-linux2.6-x86_64# ./mysql -ubill -panotherpass -hlocalhost
    Welcome to the MySQL monitor (...)

    mysql> SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();
    +----------------+----------------+
    | USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
    +----------------+----------------+
    | bill@localhost | @localhost     |
    +----------------+----------------+
    1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Conclusion 1, from edit 1: One can authenticate as `'bill'@'%'`through a socket.

Conclusion 2, from edit 2: Whether one connects through TCP or through a socket has no impact on the authentication process (except one cannot connect as anyone else but `'something'@'localhost'` through a socket, obviously).

Conclusion 3, from edit 3: Although I specified `-ubill`, I have been granted access as an anonymous user. This is because of the "sorting rules" advised above. Notice that in most default installations, [a no-password, anonymous user exists](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/default-privileges.html) (and should be secured/removed).

Comment: For anyone curious as to why 'bill'@'localhost' matches ''@'localhost' like I was, an empty string effectively acts a wild card in MySQL's authentication algorithm.

Comment: A short query `RENAME USER ''@'localhost' TO ''@'%';` made my day! Thank you!

Comment: @Sanja Be extra careful with this workaround. You may be allowing anonymous access to your database from any location. In case of doubt, I would rather delete the user.

Comment: @RandomSeed Thank you for this comment! Probably I should just delete anonymous user. P.S. I found http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html that says that these users surely can be deleted: `DROP USER ''@'localhost';`. They are not needed for some special purpose.

Comment: I dropped the anonymous user, but things still did not work. Then I found that I needed to issue also "FLUSH PRIVILEGES". It would be helpful to mention that also.

Comment: @NeemePraks This is probably because you dropped this user by [directly manipulating the `mysql.user` table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privilege-changes.html). `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` shouldn't be required if you rather `DROP USER ''@localhost`

Comment: Yep, that is true, I just deleted the row from "user" table.

Comment: @Ali Why not choose this as best answer?

Comment: I'm so glad to have found this. My day was almost ruined! I'd put hours of time into looking for the error and I've come to find that it was all due to some stupid `''@'localhost'`. We live and we learn!

Comment: excellent, wonder why it took me days to find this, why it's stuck on page 20 or so of google results most of which are all sites leeching other comments from SO...

Comment: Spent a day on this, it was finally looking through multiple users in mysql.user that led me to it, from this answer.

Comment: I used the `sudo mysql_secure_installation` command to remove the anonymous users

Comment: This is the answer! Why does this not come in bold capital letters in every mysql manual. DELETE THE ANONYMOUS USER OR IT WILL KILL ALL YOUR ATTEMPTS TO LOGIN FROM LOCALHOST!

Comment: I am working with MariaDB.  I dropped the anonymous user, but still had issues.  I could connect via Workbench, but not through my web service using the same account and port information.  I ended up creating a new user account which works.  This answer did help me find the right approach. There are a few other user accounts in MariaDB that may have prevented my original account from working.

Comment: I am using the CakePHP 3.4.0 and was getting the same error. I have XAMPP on OS X Sierra. So after fixing the path on CLI and dropping the anonymous users (ANY), it started working. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see such a user in my table but have the same error as the OP...maybe there's a bug in new ubuntu dist of mysql?

Comment: Sweet! This was it!

Answer (score 165):

Try:

```
~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter Password:

mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to bill@localhost identified by 'pass' with grant option;
```

Comment: This is rather dangerous, if someone hacks your bill@localhost mysql account, he will have infinite access to all the databases of your mysql server.

Comment: Whehey.  I had to put quote around my user 'myusername'@'myhost.static.myip.com'  then it worked.

Comment: That works for me but I'm afraid I gave too much privileges for the user

Comment: @CsabaToth you did, reduce the privileges again until your user has what he needs and no more.

Comment: ... and what do you do if this gives you "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" then ?

Comment: Important that you be careful using `WITH GRANT OPTION`. From the MySQL manual `The GRANT OPTION privilege enables you to give to other users or remove from other users those privileges that you yourself possess.`. Don't use it for any user that pulls data for a public source (i.e. a website)

Comment: In place of `*.*`, we can also insert the name of the database to which this user is authorized.

Comment: Thank you. After 2 days of hard time, I found a solution with your answer.

Answer (score 108):

When you ran

```
mysql -u bill -p
```

and got this error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

mysqld is expecting you to connect as `bill@localhost`

Try creating `bill@localhost`

```
CREATE USER bill@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'passpass';
grant all privileges on *.* to bill@localhost with grant option;
```

If you want to connect remotely, you must specify either the DNS name, the public IP, or 127.0.0.1 using TCP/IP:

```
mysql -u bill -p -hmydb@mydomain.com
mysql -u bill -p -h10.1.2.30
mysql -u bill -p -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=TCP
```

Once you login, please run this

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

[USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL

[CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL from the **mysql.user** table

This will give you a better view of how and why you were allowed to login to mysql. Why is this view important to know? It has to do with the user authentication ordering protocol.

Here is an example: I will create an anonymous user on my desktop MySQL

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+---------+-----------+
| user    | host      |
+---------+-----------+
| lwdba   | %         |
| mywife  | %         |
| lwdba   | 127.0.0.1 |
| root    | 127.0.0.1 |
| lwdba   | localhost |
| root    | localhost |
| vanilla | localhost |
+---------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> grant all on *.* to x@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+---------+-----------+
| user    | host      |
+---------+-----------+
| lwdba   | %         |
| mywife  | %         |
| x       | %         |
| lwdba   | 127.0.0.1 |
| root    | 127.0.0.1 |
| lwdba   | localhost |
| root    | localhost |
| vanilla | localhost |
+---------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update mysql.user set user='' where user='x';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+---------+-----------+
| user    | host      |
+---------+-----------+
|         | %         |
| lwdba   | %         |
| mywife  | %         |
| lwdba   | 127.0.0.1 |
| root    | 127.0.0.1 |
| lwdba   | localhost |
| root    | localhost |
| vanilla | localhost |
+---------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

OK watch me login as anonymous user:

```
C:\MySQL_5.5.12>mysql -urol -Dtest -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=TCP
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 5.5.12-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select user(),current_user();
+---------------+----------------+
| user()        | current_user() |
+---------------+----------------+
| rol@localhost | @%             |
+---------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Authentication ordering is very strict. It checks from the most specific to the least. [**I wrote about this authentiation style in the DBA StackExchange**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10897/877).

Don't forget to explicitly call for TCP as the protocol for mysql client when necessary.

Comment: `'bill'@'localhost'` should match `'bill@%'`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Yak the sort order is not based solely on mysql.user's user column. MySQL does not do any character matching per se. I wrote about the user authentication ordering protocol in the DBA StackExchange : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10897/877

Comment: @YaK This is why I specifically mentioned `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();`. You almost never see anonymous users appear from these two functions except in really poor setups.

Comment: I never assumed the sort order is based **solely** on `mysql.user`. In fact, if you read my answer again, you will see that I said (actually, the manual says) the sort order is based on the `host` column first. You wrote a lot about how to check your current credentials, but I see little information as to why `'bill'@'localhost'` cannot login as `'bill'@'%'`, which is today's question AFAIK. The OP probably has a poor setup, this is why he gets these errors.

Comment: Note that in default "binary" installations, an anonymous user ''@'localhost' exists before you run the "Post-installation" procedure. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html

Comment: Error 1045 is explained here: http://www.webyog.com/faq/content/23/18/en/error-no-1045-connection-denied.html

Answer (score 44):

Super late to this

I tried all of these other answers and ran many different versions of `mysql -u root -p` but never just ran

---

`mysql -u root -p`

And just pressing `[ENTER]` for the password.

---

Once I did that it worked. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 25):

I had a somewhat similar problem - on my first attempt to enter MySQL, as `root`, it told me access denied. Turns out I forgot to use the `sudo`...

So, if you fail on `root` first attempt, try:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

and then enter your password, this should work.

Answer (score 23):

When you type `mysql -u root -p` , you're connecting to the mysql server over a local unix socket.

However the grant you gave, `'bill'@'%'` only matches TCP/IP connections curiously enough.

If you want to grant access to the local unix socket, you need to grant privileges to 'bill'@'localhost' , which curiously enough is not the same as 'bill'@'127.0.0.1'

You could also connect using TCP/IP with the mysql command line client, as to match the privileges you already granted, e.g. run `mysql -u root -p -h 192.168.1.123` or whichever local IP address your box have.

Comment: "'bill'@'%' only matches TCP/IP connections" This is wrong. Try it on a clean (virgin, out-of-the-box) instance with `skip-networking`

Comment: @YaK I cannot get 'user'@'%' to function in such a setup, what do you mean was supposed to happen ?

Comment: I could connect as 'bill'@'%' on a v5.0 without networking (hence, through a socket). What version are you using? I will try it on a v5.5.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I was able to login as `'bill'@'%'` through a socket on a v5.5.

Answer (score 23):

A related problem in my case was trying to connect using :

```
mysql -u mike -p mypass
```

**Whitespace** IS apparently allowed between the -u #uname# but **NOT** between the -p and #password#

Therefore needed:

```
mysql -u mike -pmypass
```

Otherwise with white-space between -p **mypass** mysql takes 'mypass' as the **db** name

Comment: or: mysql -u usrname -p -- this stops anyone from seeing the password as it will drop a new line and ask for the password without displaying it

Comment: great answer @mstram

Comment: this solution is comfortable, nevertheless it's insecure to type password obviously, but no need type grant privileges and define other stuff. So if you mac book is secured – this approach very comfortable, even more I used it for importing data to aws from docker mysql driver.

Answer (score 22):

If you forget your password or you want to modify your password.You can follow these steps :

> 1 :stop your mysql
>
> > [root@maomao ~]# service mysqld stop
> >     Stopping MySQL:                                            [  OK  ]
>
> 2 :use  “--skip-grant-tables” to restart mysql
>
> > [root@mcy400 ~]# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables 
> >     [root@cy400 ~]# Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
>
> 3 : open a new window and input mysql -u root
>
> > [root@cy400 ~]# mysql -u root 
> >     Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>
> 4 : change the user database
>
> > mysql> use mysql 
> >     Reading table information for completion of table and column names
> >     You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
> >     Database changed
>
> 5 : modify your password your new password should be input in "（）"
>
> > mysql> update user set password=password('root123') where user='root'; 
> >     Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec) 
> >     Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0
>
> 6 : flush
>
> > mysql> flush privileges;
>
> 7: quit
>
> > mysql> quit 
> >     Bye
>
> 8: restart mysql
>
> > [root@cy400 ~]# service mysqld restart; 
> >     Stopping MySQL:                                            [  OK  ] 
> >     Starting MySQL:                                            [  OK  ]

Bingo！ You can connect your database with your username and new password:

```
[root@cy400 ~]# mysql -u root -p <br>
Enter password: admin123 <br>
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. <br>
Your MySQL connection id is 2 <br>
Server version: 5.0.77 Source distribution <br>
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer. <br>
mysql> quit <br>
Bye
```

Comment: This helped me, but on mac if you install with homebrew it's `mysql.server stop`. In my case, I couldn't update the user column because there isn't one; also couldn't create one because it's in safe mode. For what I'm doing right now I don't care, but I really appreciate this format answer with exact inputs & outputs shown. thanks!

Comment: I'am sorry ,I have never use mac before.So I can not help you.

Comment: Thank you, It was very very usefull to me, you saved my day and night :)

Answer (score 19):

Save yourself of a MAJOR headache... Your problem might be that you are missing the quotes around the password. At least that was my case that detoured me for 3 hours.

```
[client]
user = myusername
password = "mypassword"   # <----------------------- VERY IMPORTANT (quotes)
host = localhost
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Search for "Here is a typical user option file:" and see the example they state in there. Good luck, and I hope to save someone else some time.

Comment: THANK YOU for this. I've wasted half of a day on this and the stupid quotes around password did the trick!

Comment: Haha. I wasted pretty much the same when it happened to me. Glad to be of help.

Comment: Yep. This happened to me as well in the laravel .env file. No quotes and wasn't working. Thanks. :)

Comment: thanks, bro for this tip, I have also wasted my day on this. working fine with quotes in laravel env.

Answer (score 13):

The solution is to  delete the anonymous (Any) user!

I also faced the same issue on a server setup by someone else. I normally don't choose to create an anonymous user upon installing MySQL, so hadn't noticed this. Initially I logged in as "root" user and created a couple of "normal" users (aka users with privileges only on dbs with their username as prefix), then logged out, then went on to verify the first normal user. I couldn't log in. Neither via phpMyAdmin, nor via shell. Turns out, the culprit is this "Any" user.

Answer (score 9):

The best solution i found for myself is.

my user is sonar and whenever i am trying to connect to my database from external or other machine i am getting error as

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sonar'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Also as i am trying this from another machine and through Jenkins job my URL for accessing is

```
alm-lt-test.xyz.com
```

if you want to connect remotely you can specify it with different ways as follows:

```
mysql -u sonar -p -halm-lt-test.xyz.com
mysql -u sonar -p -h101.33.65.94
mysql -u sonar -p -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=TCP
mysql -u sonar -p -h172.27.59.54 --protocol=TCP
```

To access this with URL you just have to execute the following query.

```
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'alm-lt-test.xyz.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'172.27.59.54' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
```

Answer (score 9):

It's a difference between:

```
CREATE USER 'bill'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passpass';
```

and

```
CREATE USER 'bill'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passpass';
```

Check it:

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+---------------+----------------------------+
| user          | host                       |
+---------------+----------------------------+
| bill          | %                          | <=== created by first
| root          | 127.0.0.1                  |
| root          | ::1                        |
| root          | localhost                  |
| bill          | localhost                  | <=== created by second
+---------------+----------------------------+
```

The command

```
mysql -u bill -p
```

access implicit to 'bill'@'localhost' and NOT to 'bill'@'%'.

There are no permissions for 'bill'@'localhost'

you get the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

solving the problem:

```
CREATE USER 'bill'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passpass';

grant all privileges on . to 'bill'@'localhost' with grant option;
```

Comment: The grant statement returned an error. I needed to specify a database like so: grant all privileges on newdb.* to ....

Comment: `grant all privileges on *.* to 'bill'@'localhost' with grant option;` Correction to query

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I'm not sure but probably this is my.cnf file inside mysql installation directory is the culprit.
Comment out this line and the problem might be resolved.

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: For more details, you can view this as well http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/MySQL

Comment: I am quite sure that this is not the issue. If it would be, MySQL refuses connections from any host other than 127.0.0.1, and you will not get a SQL 'Access Denied' error.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if anyone else will find this helpful, but I encountered the same error and searched all over for any anonymous users...and there weren't any. The problem ended up being that the user account was set to "Require SSL" - which I found in PHPMyAdmin by going to User Accounts and clicking on Edit Privileges for the user. As soon as I unchecked this option, everything worked as expected!

Answer (score 5):

This also happens when your password contains some special characters like @,$,etc.
To avoid this situation you can wrap password in single quotes:

```
$ mysql -usomeuser -p's0mep@$$w0Rd'
```

Or instead don't use password while entering. Leave it blank and then type it when terminal asks. This is the recommended way.

```
$ mysql -usomeuser -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 191
Server version: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Comment: This can indeed be an issue (as it was for me). All my passwords for any of my accounts are generated using `pwgen`. Today I generated a new one for a MySQL database and its user. Unfortunately the password contained a backslash "\" which I didn't identify as the errors origin (I didn't even think of that). So, I searched for hours a solution. After setting the password to "123" in despair the login finally worked. … Users should be aware of that some special chars may cause problems since MySQL doesn't show any warnings on using passwords such as "daiy4ha4in7chooshuiphie\Th*aew", for example.

Comment: Was about to post this as an answer if it hadn't shown up yet, it was simply too far down the list for me to notice (so I'm bumping it up +1)

Comment: Thanks for this. I've encountered it before and just couldn't remember! Got tied up with the difference between '127.0.0.1' and 'localhost'.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** On v8.0.15 (maybe this version) the `PASSWORD()` function does not work.

You have to:

1. Make sure you have Stopped MySQL first.
2. Run the server in safe mode with privilege bypass: `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`
3. Login: `mysql -u root`
4. mysql> `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';`
5. mysql> `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
6. mysql> `exit;`
7. Login again: `mysql -u root`
8. mysql> `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'yourpasswd';`

Answer (score 5):

For me root had a default password

i changed the password using `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new Password';` and it worked

Comment: I got an error `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'user'@'localhost'`

Comment: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I updated the user I created privately with the same password. problem fixed for me too. mysql 8.0.34

Comment: i set root and user password same. after changing new user password issue is solved.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you have not done more damage by also deleting the debian-sys-maint user in mysql

Have your mysql daemon running the normal way. Start your mysql client as shown below

```
mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
```

In another terminal, `cat` the file `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`. That file contains a password; paste that password when prompted for it.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1836919

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to let you know a unusual circumstance I received the same error. Perhaps this helps someone in the future.

I had developed a few base views, created at the development site and transferred them to the production-site. Later that week I changed a PHP script and all of a sudden errors came up that Access was denied for user 'local-web-user'@'localhost'. The datasource object had not changed, so I concentrated on the database user in MySQL, worrying  in the meantime someone hacked my website. Luckily the rest of the site seemed unharmed.

It later turned out that the views were the culprit(s). Our object transfers are done using another (and remote: admin@ip-address) user than the local website user. So the views were created with 'admin'@'ip-address' as the definer. The view creation SECURITY default is

```
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
```

When local-web-user tries to use the view it stumbles on the lacking privileges of the definer to use the tables. Once security was changed to:

```
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
```

the issue was resolved. The actual problem was completely different than anticipated based on the error message.

Comment: This ended up being the source of my problem as well - a view with a missing "definer".  One quick way to find out if this is what's happening to you is to try querying the same table or view as root - if you do, the error message changes to the much more descriptive "ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer does not exist".

Answer (score 4):

For me, this problem was caused by a new feature of MySQL 5.7.2: `user` entries are *ignored* if their `plugin` field is empty.

Set it to e.g. `mysql_native_password` to reenable them:

```
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE user='foo';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

See [the release notes for MySQL 5.7.2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-2.html), under «Authentication Notes».

For some reason (maybe because my pre-4.1 password hashes were removed), the `mysql_upgrade` script didn't set a default plugin value.

I found out by noticing the following warning message in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`:

> [Warning] User entry 'foo'@'%' has an empty plugin value. The user will  be ignored and no one can login with this user anymore.

I post this answer here to maybe save someone from using the same ridiculous amount of time on this as I did.

Answer (score 4):

**Debugging Summary**

- Check for typo error: username or password.
- Check the host name and compare it with mysql.user table host name.
- Check user exists or not.
- Check whether host contains IP address or host name.

*There is a great chance that, you might have encountered this issue multiple times in your work. This issue occurred to me most of times due to the incorrectly entering user name or password. Though this is one of the reasons, there are other many chances you might get this issue. Sometimes, it looks very similar, but when you dig deeper, you will realize multiple factors contributing to this error. This post will explain in detail, most of the common reasons and work around to fix this issue.*

**Possible reasons:**

- **Case 1: Typo error: username or password.**

*This is the most common reason for this error. If you entered the username or password wrongly, surely you will get this error.*

**Solution:**

*Solution for this type of error is very simple. Just enter the correct username and password. This error will be resolved. In case if you forget the password you can reset the username/password.
If you forget the password for admin / root account, there are many ways to reset / recapture the root password. I will publish another post on how to reset the root password in-case if you forget root password.*

- **Case 2: Accessing from wrong host.**

*MySQL provides host based restriction for user access as a security features. In our production environment, we used to restrict the access request only to the Application servers. This feature is really helpful in many production scenarios.*

**Solution:**

*When you face this type of issue, first check whether your host is allowed or not by checking the mysql.user table.
If it is not defined, you can update or insert new record to mysql.user table.
Generally, accessing as a root user from remote machine is disabled and it is not a best practice, because of security concerns.
If you have requirements to access your server from multiple machines, give access only to those machines. It is better not to use wildcards (%) and gives universal accesses.
Let me update the mysql.user table, now the demouser can access MySQL server from any host.*

- **Case 3: User does not exists on the server.**

This type of error occurs when the user, which you are trying to access not exist on the MySQL server.

**Solutions:**

When you face this type of issue, just check whether the user is exists in mysql.user table or not. If the record not exists, user cannot access. If there is a requirement for that user to access, create a new user with that username.

- **Case 4: Mix of numeric and name based hosts.**

**Important points**

- It is not advisable to use wildcards while defining user host, try to use the exact host name.
- Disable root login from remote machine.
- Use proxy user concept.

*There are few other concepts related with this topic and getting into details of those topics is very different scope of this article. We will look into the following related topics in the upcoming articles.*

- What to do, if you forgot root password in of MySQL server.
- MySQL Access privilege issues and user related tables.
- MySQL security features with best practices.

*I hope this post will help for you to fix the MySQL Error Code 1045 Access denied for user in MySQL.*

Comment: This was it :) I just had a wrong pw. In my case, I thought I would be able to copy a pw out of the db management system from the disguised black dots, very much wondering about this, and it turned out that I had another pw still in the clipboard instead. Well... Good that one cannot just copy a pw from a db manager :).

Answer (score 4):

I discovered yet another case that appears on the surface to be an edge case; I can export to the file system, via SELECT INTO .. OUTFILE as root, but not as regular user. While this may be a matter of permissions, I've looked at that, and see nothing especially obvious. All I can say is that executing the query as a regular user who has all permissions on the data base in question returns the access denied error that led me to this topic. When I found the transcript of a successful use of SELECT INTO … OUTFILE in an old project, I noticed that I was logged in as root. Sure enough, when I logged in as root, the query ran as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This may apply to very few people, but here goes. Don't use an exclamation `!` in your password.

I did and got the above error using MariaDB. When I simplified it to just numbers and letters it worked. Other characters such as `@` and `$` work fine - I used those characters in a different user on the same instance.

The fifth response at this [address](http://forums.sentora.org/showthread.php?tid=970&pid=6356#pid6356) led me to my fix.

Comment: Yes, this is true, my password was a mix of numbers, letters, and these chars `-::)(&/&\)/` and guess what, the backslash was causing me the issue!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems because my password contains ";" char breaking my password when I creates it at first moment. Caution with this if can help you.

Comment: Same as @Chiwda issue! sometimes it's just the password itself

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays! Solution for:

> MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'
> (using password: YES);

**Wampserver 3.2.0 new installation or upgrading**

Probably `xamp` using `mariaDB` as default is well.

`Wamp` server comes with `mariaDB` and mysql, and installing `mariaDB` as default on 3306 port and mysql on 3307, port sometimes 3308.

Connect to `mysql`!

On installation, it asks to use `mariaDB` or `MySql`. But mariaDB is checked as default and you can't change it; check `mysql` option and install.

When installation is done, both will be running `mariaDB` on default port 3306 and `mysql` on another port 3307 or 3308.

Right click on the `wampserver` icon where it's running.  It should be on the right bottom corner; go to tools and see your correct `mysql` running port.

And include it in your database connection as follows:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';
$port = '3308';//Port

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;port=$port;charset=$charset"; //Add in connection
$options = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
try {
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
```

`Note :` I am using pdo.

See here for more : https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/

Comment: Please do not use backticks for emphasis. They should only be used for code. Words like MySQL or Wampserver are not code.

Comment: `Right Click wampmanager->Tools->Invert Default DBMS` will allow you to make either MySQL or mariaDB the default (the one using port 3306) This way you dont have to add stuff to your code that wont work when you move it live.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -i 
mysql -u root
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
```

access mysql service without login ( can see beacue in shell mysql> )

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, here's how to resolve:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

1. Uninstall mysql from the control panel
2. Delete the MySql folder from `C:\Program Files,C:\Program Files (x86)` and `C:\ProgramData`
3. Install mysql

Comment: Tried all other answers, finally resolved to try this and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

For me, It was not specifying the `-p` parameter when entering mysql.

```
mysql -p
```

I had no problem, but it was wrong to invoke mysql without a password.

Answer (score 1):

So for me the issue was related to the ports i'm mapping.

3306 => 3306 did not work(because I had a local mysql running)

3307 => 3306 works!

This is in the context of establishing as ssh tunnel:

```
ssh -N -L 3307:rdsDns:3306 ec2User@ec2Dns -i key.pem -v
```

3307 is the local port, and 3306 is the remote port.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `mysql -u bill -p`, `localhost` is resolved to your ip, since it is 127.0.0.1 and in your `/etc/hosts` file, as default `127.0.0.1       localhost` exists. So, mysql interprets you as `bill@localhost` which is not granted with `bill@'%'` . This is why there are 2 different records for `root` user in result of `select host, user from mysql.user;` query.

There are two ways to handle this issue.

One is specifying an ip which is not reversely resolved by `/etc/hosts` file when you try to login. For example, the ip of server is `10.0.0.2`. When you run the command `mysql -u bill -p -h 10.0.0.2`, you will be able to login. If you type `select user();`, you will get `bill@10.0.0.2`. Of course, any domain name should not be resolved to this ip in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Secondly, you need grant access for this specific domain name. For `bill@localhost`, you should call command `grant all privileges on *.* to bill@localhost identified by 'billpass';` . In this case, you will be able to login with command `mysql -u bill -p`. Once logined, `select user();` command returns `bill@localhost`.

But this is only for that you try to login a mysql server in the same host. From remote hosts, mysql behaves expectedly, '%' will grant you to login.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by deleting the old buggy user 'bill' entries (this is the important part: both from **mysql.user** and **mysql.db**), then created the same user as sad before:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
CREATE USER bill@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'passpass';
grant all privileges on *.* to bill@localhost with grant option;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Worked, user is connecting. Now I'll remove some previlegies from it :)

Answer (score 0):

OS: windows

My error message is:

> MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My reason is that I didn't open cmd with *administrator* permissions.

So my solution was to open cmd as administrator, then it worked.

Comment: This is only relevant to windows.

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen if MySQL is running on a case-insensitive OS, such as Windows.

e.g. I found that attempting to connect to a database using these credentials failed:

mysql> `grant select on databaseV105.* to 'specialuser' identified by 's3curepa5wrd';`

`$ mysql -specialuser' -p's3curepa5wrd' -h10.61.130.89 databaseV105`

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'specialuser'@'10.0.1.113' (using password: YES)

But, this succeeded:

mysql> `grant select on databasev105.* to 'specialuser' identified by 's3curepa5wrd';`

`$ mysql -specialuser' -h10.300.300.400 databaseV105 -p`

> Enter password:

Answer (score 0):

If your dbname, username, password, etc strings lengths exceed values outlined at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant-tables.html#grant-tables-scope-column-properties , you might also fail to log in, as this was in my case.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the server hosting my code was sending '@blablabla.amazonaws.com' at the ed of the username when trying to log into MySQL. So I had to add  %.amazonws.com into my hosting's user config (dreamhost) and it went through

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem can be very simple!

1. In my case I had exported my database (mysqldump) into a dumpfile.
2. Then I copied the file, to the destination server.
3. On this destination server I created the target database
4. Then I ran the command to import the copied dumpfile to the new target database on my destination server.

==> ERROR! At this point I just got the error that you got too!

Now, think about it! The user you use, what GRANT's does he have on the source database?

An what GRANT's does he have on the new target database?
I think, you see allready the problem and also the solution!

==> SOLUTION!

5. So I went into my source database and exported all the grants of the user I use.
6. After that I went to my target database and imported the exported GRANT's.

A voila! After that the import of the source database on the target server into the new target database work without any problems!

It's a lot of text, sorry! but maybe it will help someone solve a problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you have freshly installed the mysql-server on you linux machine then
here is the solution

try running this

```bash
sudo mysql
```

then create user for login to database , not alsways using above command

Answer (score 0):

for me
putting "password" on the passoword solved the problem

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=realxcqv_ppcLeads
DB_USERNAME=realxcqv_UserPPcLeads
DB_PASSWORD="PPC@199#@199#PPCLeads@199#@199#"
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQL account names consist of a user name and a host name, The name 'localhost' in host name  indicates the local host also You can use the wildcard characters “%” and “_” in host name or IP address values. These have the same meaning as for pattern-matching operations performed with the LIKE operator. For example, a host value of '%' matches any host name, whereas a value of '%.mysql.com' matches any host in the mysql.com domain. '192.168.1.%' matches any host in the 192.168.1 class C network.

Above was just introduction:

actually both users `'bill'@'localhost'` and `'bill'@'%'` are different MySQL accounts, hence both should use their own authentication details like password.

For more information refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/account-names.html

Answer (score -1):

Be sure there are no other SQL instances running that are using the localhost post. In our case another instance was running on the localhost that conflicted with the login. Turning it off solved this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Also the problem can occur if you are using old version of the MySQL UI (like SQLYoug) that generates passwords with wrong hash.

Creating user with SQL script will fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but in my case the solution was solved by the comment by eggyal.  I had an anonymous user as well, but removing it didn't solve the problem.  The 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' command worked though.

The surprising thing to me about this was that I created the user with MySQL Workbench and I would have expected that to perform all of the necessary functions to complete the task.

Answer (score -1):

For Mac users if they still have the problem (as was my case), I found this solution worked for me: [MySQL command line '-bash command not found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391778/mysql-command-line-bash-command-not-found)

To use command i.e. `mysql` on macbook terminal you need to export path using:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

Considering default installation, use following command to get mysql prompt as root user:

```
mysql -u root
```

Otherwise you are using wrong root password.

Ref: Setting the MySQL root user password on OSX

Answer (score -1):

The percent sign means all ip's so localhost is superfluous ... There is no need of the second record with the localhost .

Actually there is, 'localhost' is special in mysql, it means a connection over a unix socket (or named pipes on windows I believe) as opposed to a TCP/IP socket. using % as the host does not include 'localhost'

MySQL user accounts have two components: a user name and a host name. The user name identifies the user, and the host name specifies what hosts that user can connect from. The user name and host name are combined to create a user account:

`'<user_name>'@'<host_name>'`
You can specify a specific IP address or address range for host name, or use the percent character ("%") to enable that user to log in from any host.

Note that user accounts are defined by both the user name and the host name. For example, `'root'@'%'` is a different user account than `'root'@'localhost'`.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same error. The setup that wasn't working is as follows:

```
define("HOSTNAME", "localhost");
define("HOSTUSER", "van");
define("HOSTPASS", "helsing");
define("DBNAME", "crossbow");
$connection = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME, HOSTUSER, HOSTPASS);
```

The edited setup below is the one that got it working. Notice the difference?

```
define('HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('HOSTUSER', 'van');
define('HOSTPASS', 'helsing');
define('DBNAME', 'crossbow');
$connection = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME, HOSTUSER, HOSTPASS);
```

The difference is the double quotes. They seem to be quite significant in PHP as opposed to Java and they have an impact when it comes to escaping characters, setting up URLs and now, passing parameters to a function. They're prettier (I know) but always use single quotes as much as possible then double quotes can be nested within those if necessary.

This error came up when I tested my application on a Linux box as opposed to a Windows environment.