# ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';

Tags: mysql

Mistakenly I deleted my root user from my `mysql.user` table.

```
delete from mysql.user where user='username';
```

To make same root user, I am trying to fire below query,

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

I get error as

`ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'username'@'localhost'`

As per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost), I tried `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`, but still I get same error.

Any idea what is going wrong?

---

### Answer

I also had to delete the same from `mysql.db` table

```
delete from mysql.db where user='username';
```

That's it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use `DROP USER` command to remove the user, then the user gets removed completely. If you have to add user with same username later, you can use FLUSH PRIVILEGES command to completely remove privileges from the mysql memory.

```
DROP USER username@hostname;
```

You have to `restart mysql` or run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` before creating the same user because there are issues with privileges. 
To restart mysql in linux based systems

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

to restart in windows systems

```
net stop mysql
net start mysql
```

To flush privilege in mysql prompt

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You can alternatively use `REVOKE` command if you know which privileges that the user has

```
REVOKE privillege1, privillege2, ... FROM deleted_user@host
```

Answer (score 1):

This user must be referenced in other tables from the `mysql` system schema. I would recreate the user the same way you deleted it:

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user (user, host, password)
VALUES ('root', 'localhost', PASSWORD('pasw'));
```

Then

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

Yet another reason to never mess with this schema (sorry, I couldn't help).

Answer (score 0):

As for the above, `password` field does not exist in my case and mysql throws an error.

This command helped:

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user (user, host, ssl_cipher, x509_issuer, x509_subject, plugin, authentication_string) VALUES ('user', 'localhost', '', '', '', 'mysql_native_password', PASSWORD('pass'));
```