# Can't create user in mysql for sonarqube

Tags: mysql, database, jenkins

I'm trying to set up a remote user for sonarqube :

```
USE mysql
CREATE USER sonar@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

But I get this error :

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'sonar'@'%'
```

Any idea ?

EDIT :

I tried to `flush privileges;` but same result after that.

EDIT 2 :

The [duplicate proposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008610/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-usernamelocalhost-iden) does not match my issue..

To be precise the users are to be created in `mysql` database, which is why I don't do CREATE DATABASE but only CREATE

Comment: Possible dup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost

Comment: As I said I tried this already :)

Comment: In the CREATE USER MySQL documentation they are using qoutes around the username.. So try `CREATE USER 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: Could you show the results for `SELECT user,host FROM user;`.

Comment: Please show the results for `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user`