# while creating and deleting user in mysql ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create new user in mysql,

```
    create user 'saravanakumar'@'localhost' identified by 'saravanakumar';
```

it shows error as,

```
    ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'saravanakumar'@'localhost'
```

after I read this

[ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'jack'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost)

I delete user.But I can't.It shows

```
    mysql> SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
    +---------------+
    | User          |
    +---------------+
    | root          |
    | saravanakumar |
    | saravanakumar |
    |               |
    | root          |
    | saravanakumar |
    |               |
    | root          |
    +---------------+
    8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
    +---------------+
    | User          |
    +---------------+
    | root          |
    | saravanakumar |
    | saravanakumar |
    |               |
    | root          |
    | saravanakumar |
    |               |
    | root          |
    +---------------+
    8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

how can i delete all these user in table and how can i create a single user.What is the root cause of this problem? experts please help me.

Comment: What does `select user, host from mysql.user` show? The duplicate users in the table should have different hosts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'saravanakumar'@'localhost'
```

Does indeed indicate that the user already exists or did exist.

FLUSH PRIVILEGES doesn't delete users.

```
Reloads the privileges from the grant tables in the mysql database.

The server caches information in memory as a result of GRANT, CREATE USER, 
CREATE SERVER, and INSTALL PLUGIN statements. This memory is not released 
by the corresponding REVOKE, DROP USER, DROP SERVER, and UNINSTALL PLUGIN 
statements, so for a server that executes many instances of the statements 
that cause caching, there will be an increase in memory use. 
This cached memory can be freed with FLUSH PRIVILEGES.
```

You are looking for DROP USER.

```
DROP USER user [, user] ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-user.html

---

Order of buisness would be:

```
DROP USER 'saravanakumar'@HOSTNAME;
CREATE USER 'saravanakumar'@HOSTNAME [IDENTIFIED BY 'password'];
```

---

You will probably need to flush privileges if you use delete from (do not).
**Remember**: this does not necessarily revoke all the privileges this user may have (like table privileges), you will have to do this yourself - *if you don't you may not be able to recreate the user*.

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'saravanakumar'@HOSTNAME;
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='saravanakumar';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
CREATE USER 'saravanakumar'@HOSTNAME [IDENTIFIED BY 'password'];
```

---

"user" requires you to specify an account name

```
Syntax for account names is 'user_name'@'host_name'
```

and

```
An account name consisting only of a user name is equivalent 
to 'user_name'@'%'. For example, 'me' is equivalent to 'me'@'%'.
```

Additional reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-names.html

---

Please read those bug reports for further clarification

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28331

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62255

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I unfortunately delete all users including root,finally I have read permission root only. Because of I while deleting user it shows some error internally delete users.I saw above link, it have a bug about this issue in FEDORA and CENTOS while delete user by query in lower case.Finally I uninstall the  mysql and reinstall it. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

To me works, I set hostname in UPPERCASE:

DROP USER 'user'@'LOCALHOST'

Answer (score 0):

```
select User, Host from mysql.user;
```

Made it clear for me what was happening. I had ended up with the same user under several hosts. Deleting unwanted ones helped!