# ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'user'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, sql-drop

I have created a user in mysql. Now i want to delete the user ? How to do that? I am getting this error :

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'user'@'localhost'
```

I am using this command :

```
DROP USER 'user'@'localhost';
```

Its an amazon machine.

Thanks

Comment: This command is working for me:

delete from mysql.user where user='user_name' and host = 'localhost';

Comment: delete from mysql.user where user='user_name';

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It was because i created the user using command :

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';
```

and i was deleting it using :

```
drop user 'user'@'localhost';
```

and i should have used this command :

```
drop user 'user'@'%';
```

Comment: delete from mysql.user where user='user_name';

Comment: And yet, when I `drop user 'user'@'%';` (before and after flushing privileges, I still get the HY000 failure. This answer would be improved by pointing out that there are different values that may be delimited by the second set of single quotes.

Comment: Execute `select user,host from mysql.user` to see which host belongs after the `@`.

Answer (score 60):

It is likely that the user you are trying to drop does not exist. You can confirm (or not) whether this is the case by running:

```
select user,host
from mysql.user
where user = '<your-user>';
```

If the user does exist then try running:

```
flush privileges;

drop user 'user'@'localhost';
```

Another thing to check is to make sure you are logged in as `root` user

If all else fails then you can manually remove the user like this:

```
delete from mysql.user
where user='<your-user>'
and host = 'localhost';

flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 17):

How to solve problem like this:

```
mysql> drop user 'q10'@'localhost';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'q10'@'localhost'
```

First:you should check what host of your user,such as:

---

```
mysql> select host,user from user;
+-----------+------+
| host      | user |
+-----------+------+
| %         | q10  |
| localhost | root |
| localhost | sy   |
| localhost | tom  |
+-----------+------+
```

if I drop user 'q10',the command is :

```
mysql> drop user 'q10'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

And if I drop user 'tom',the command as follow:

```
mysql> drop user 'tom'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: delete from mysql.user where user='user_name';

Answer (score 2):

Try using 'user'@'localhost' without quotes:

`DROP USER user@localhost;`

It should work that way in MySQL 8. I also had that problem.

Answer (score 2):

delete from mysql.user where user='user_name' and host = 'localhost';

flush privileges;

Working for me...