# DROP User 'netbeansuser'@'%'; throws Error HY000 (1396) MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database, drop, sql-drop

I mistakenly created a user that I am unable to delete. Following is the code snippet interacting with MySQL:

```
mysql> DROP User 'netbeansuser'@'%';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'netbeansuser'@'%'
mysql> select User from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| User             |
+------------------+
| root             |
| root             |
| debian-sys-maint |
| netbeansuser     |
| root             |
| root             |
+------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP User 'netbeansuser';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'netbeansuser'@'%'
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select User from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| User             |
+------------------+
| root             |
| root             |
| debian-sys-maint |
| netbeansuser     |
| root             |
| root             |
+------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec) 

mysql> DROP User 'netbeansuser';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'netbeansuser'@'%'
mysql> DROP User 'netbeansuser'@'%';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'netbeansuser'@'%'
```

What am I doing wrong? Particularly, what is the '%' sign at the hostname for? I didn't specify the hostname while creating the user. Any resources on understanding hostname bindings in MySQL USER creation will also help. Thanks all.

Comment: Check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost

Comment: Checked earlier. I need to delete the user. Not recreate.

Comment: Use 'localhost' instead of '%'.

Comment: @Kumar PLease file as separate answer. This works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be helpful.

Use **'localhost'** instead of **'%'**.

Answer (score 0):

I created the user `john` with the host `localhost` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE USER 'john'@'localhost';
```

But, I did not specify `localhost` to drop the user `john` as shown below:

```sql
DROP USER john;
```

Then, I got the error below:

> ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'john'@'%'

So, I specified `localhost` as shown below, then I could drop the user `john` without error:

```sql
DROP USER 'john'@'localhost';
```

Or:

```sql
DROP USER john@localhost;
```