# ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed

Tags: mysql

i was creating a db in mysql and ran commands-

```
create database projectdb;
create user 'aquaman'@'localhost' identified by password'aquaman123';
```

and it gave error-

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'aquaman'@'localhost'
```

anyone please help me how to resolve it

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Incorrect Syntax!!

You have included an extra `password` in your code.
Change the code from:

```
create user 'aquaman'@'localhost' identified by password'aquaman123';
```

TO:

```
CREATE USER 'aquaman'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'aquaman123';
```

Please check the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-user.html

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this issue having previously deleted a user of the same name directly from the user table:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='aquaman';
```

But this isn't the right way to delete a user! Having dropped the user properly, via:

```
DROP USER 'aquaman';
```

...I was once again able to successfully create a user with this name.

Comment: Though I think, in this instance, he'd need..

    DROP USER 'aquaman'@'localhost';

Or, at least, that's what seemed to work for me.

Comment: Thank's Nick! Your answer saved a lot of time. Got into that and last command saved from reinstalling the mysql. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
I faced the same issue in the below MySQL version in MAC OS - Catalina:

Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.27 MySQL Community Server - GPL

I was able to solve the issue by the below commands:

mysql> create database testdb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> create user 'test'@'%' identified by 'YourPassword$';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

or

mysql> create user 'test'@localhost identified by 'YourPassword$';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)



mysql> grant all on testdb.* to 'test'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

or

mysql> grant all on testdb.* to 'test'@localhost;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)


mysql> select user from mysql.user;
+------------------+
| user             |
+------------------+
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| root             |
| test             |
+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly these problems
1.INCORRECT SYNTAX
-->create user 'aquaman'@'localhost' identified by password'aquaman123';
'password' is not to be used here
2.MADE A USER OF SAME NAME
-->in this regard kindly remove the user COMPLETELY BY USING THE COMMAND
DROP USER 'name_of_the_user'@'localhost';