# can't create database with mysql for wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to create a user with the following command. I am getting the below error.

```
CREATE DATABASE wp-test;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-isdi' at line 1.

I am trying to install wordpress, and after following all the steps I am getting below error.

> This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

Comment: `CREATE DATABASE` is used for creating database. not user.

Comment: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wp-test; like that or maybe use backtick `wp-test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the best practice to use underscore instead of hyphens in database and table names because hyphens are not valid identifier in this condition you need to use backticks around the database name.

**Example:**

```
CREATE DATABASE `wp-test`;
```

Comment: Solved it, thanks but now while creating a user I am getting this 

`ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'suraj'@'localhost'
`

This is how I am trying `CREATE USER suraj@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Comment: @Suraj: for ERROR 1396, check this question, there are so many solution here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost

Comment: @Suraj: one case study regarding CREATE USE: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28331

Comment: I get this whole creating the user.

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE USER suraj@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 2
`

Answer (score 1):

try this sql command to create user

```
CREATE USER 'suraj'@'localhost';GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'suraj'@'localhost' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

and give user all the privileges..

Comment: I get this error now. `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE USER suraj@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 2
`

Comment: @Suraj: did u check manual? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-user.html

Comment: okk try this.....CREATE USER 'suraj'@'localhost'
  IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password' PASSWORD EXPIRE;

Comment: or you can check reference from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html