# Note Code : 1973 Can't create user 'user'@'localhost'; it already exists, Mysql

Tags: mysql

once I created a user named 'dscl' and deleted afer few days. Now when I am trying to create a user named 'dscl'it is showing me an error message as below.

**Note Code : 1973 Can't create user 'dscl'@'localhost'; it already exists**

I executed a query (`select * from mysql.user;`) to check user list  and it is not showing any user named 'dscl'.

What could be the cause?

Comment: What's to explain? If you want to know more about what `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` does, simply look it up in the MySQL manual.

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Did you forget to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after altering the grant table?**

You should do so now, so that the change (deleting `dscl`) is loaded into the server's memory.

Re-adding the user should then work.