# Can't add user with password with phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I'm using easyPHP Devserver 16.1.
I tried to add a new user with a password on phpmyadmin, but even if i put a password, when i check the users, there isn't any.

[my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSsFe.png)

I tried to change my password for root, change it also in my config.inc.php but then i couldn't view my users and database anymore so i reinstalled easyphp.
Now my question is why can i not create a user with a password on phpMyadmin  ?
When i create a new user with a password here is my sql request :

`CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS '***';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;`

Sorry for my bad english :/

**EDIT :**

So I copy and paste in the command line client and i made a mistake  :

`CREATE USER 'isaac'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS 'isaac';GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;`

i didn't change "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost'" so i had this error message :
`#1524 - Plugin '*94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29' is not loaded.`

Then i corrected my mistake :

`CREATE USER 'isaac'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS 'isaac'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'isaac'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;`

and i have this error :
`#1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed for 'isaac'@'localhost'`

Comment: Are you using the graphical tool to create the user or just entering the SQL statement yourself? Which version of phpMyAdmin are you using?

Comment: I'm using the graphical tool and the version of phpMyAdmin is  4.5.5.1

Comment: Do you get any error message when you try to add the new user?

Comment: I just get the green message "You have added a new user." and that's it. When i open the console, there is nothing except de sql request.

Comment: Can you try to copy and paste that SQL statement in the command-line client and see if the user appears in the user list when seen from phpMyAdmin? I don't have much idea what could be wrong here, I've never seen a situation where there is no error message but the user still isn't created. Very weird.

Comment: Thank you for your time isaac i added the error message i had in my post !

Comment: Try running the `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` SQL command. According to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5555328/2385479 there can be some disconnect within MySQL where it gets confused about whether or not a user actually exists. If that doesn't help, you might even try restarting the MySQL daemon.

Comment: I just uninstalled Easyphp and installed wamp and phpmyadmin work perfectly i can add user with password.
Thank you for your time !

Comment: Great, I'm glad you managed to work around the problem!

Comment: Yes and again thank you for your help !