# Docker mysql ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'

Tags: mysql, docker

I am trying to set up two containers one running Python, and the other mysql.
This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    python:
        restart: always
        build: ./budget/dockerfiles/python/
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        links:
            - db
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - ./budget/:/app:z
        entrypoint:
            - python
            - -u
            - /app/run.py

    db:
        build: ./budget/dockerfiles/mysql/
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: database-name
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
        volumes:
            - ./Dump.sql:/db/Dump.sql:z
            - ./Dump_Test.sql:/db/Dump_Test.sql:z
            - ./big_fc.sql:/db/big_fc.sql:z
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up -d --build`, the containers are built, but the mysql container crashes. In the log, it says:

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
```

I wanted to try what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost?rq=1) suggests, but I cannot even enter the container since it is crashed. Can somebody tell me what I can do?

Comment: Try using **just** MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD and MYSQL_DATABASE

Comment: @Robert, I just found an issue in github, and yeah that solves the problem. I am providing an answer right away.

Comment: @Robert, what if I do not include `MYSQL_PASSWORD`?

Comment: You don't need MYSQL_PASSWORD because it is intended for other users than root

Answer (score 101, accepted):

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/129),  the problem is setting `MYSQL_USER` to `root`. It will fail to create the second user `'root'@'%'` since it will already exist in the users table.

Therefore, this can be solved by only setting `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`, `MYSQL_DATABASE`, and `MYSQL_PASSWORD` in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: OMG this is too easy; why did this cost me so much time???

Comment: or just change the MYSQL_USER to anything different i.e. MYSQL_USER=shoot  
incase if different user is needed

Comment: @MuhammadSheraz, thanks a lot!
In my case, with Laravel Sail i used 'root' for MYSQL_USER.  Changing to (e.s. 'admin') the problem is gone