# GitHub workflow CI with MariaDB: Failed to initialize container mariadb

Tags: mariadb, github-actions

My GitHub workflow run fails due to problem with mariadb, my code and the errors are as below. Anyone can help me solve it? Thanks!

Here is my workflow:

```yaml
name: ci

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    services:
      mariadb:
        image: mariadb:latest   
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        env:
          DATABASE_HOST: 127.0.0.1
          MARIADB_DATABASE: db
          MARIADB_USER: root
          MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MARIADB_PASSWORD: password
        options: --health-cmd="healthcheck.sh --connect --innodb_initialized" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
       
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 18.18.0
    
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install

    - name: Run app
      run: npm start
    
    - name: Run integration tests
      run: npm test
```

The error messages:

```
 Status: Downloaded newer image for mariadb:latest
  docker.io/library/mariadb:latest
  /usr/bin/docker create --name 6f254062043d42239b1275be94a49fb0_mariadblatest_a5040d --label 71c3f5 --network github_network_c2a28bb3167a4ea38e9fd6e4e7ec28de --network-alias mariadb -p 3306:3306 --health-cmd="healthcheck.sh --connect --innodb_initialized" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3 -e "DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1" -e "MARIADB_DATABASE=db" -e "MARIADB_USER=root" -e "MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" -e "MARIADB_PASSWORD=password" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true mariadb:latest
  50f5710f2a561543de7646211a5bb97401a13ac930aa810c0c6f3a0855bb6888
  /usr/bin/docker start 50f5710f2a561543de7646211a5bb97401a13ac930aa810c0c6f3a0855bb6888
  50f5710f2a561543de7646211a5bb97401a13ac930aa810c0c6f3a0855bb6888
  /usr/bin/docker ps --all --filter id=50f5710f2a561543de7646211a5bb97401a13ac930aa810c0c6f3a0855bb6888 --filter status=running --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.Status}}"
  50f5710f2a561543de7646211a5bb97401a13ac930aa810c0c6f3a0855bb6888 Up Less than a second (health: starting)
  /usr/bin/docker port 50f5710f2a561543de7646211a5bb97401a13ac930aa810c0c6f3a0855bb6888
  3306/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:3306
  3306/tcp -> [::]:3306
Waiting for all services to be ready
  /usr/bin/docker inspect --format="{{if .Config.Healthcheck}}{{print .State.Health.Status}}{{end}}" 50f5710f2a561543de7646211a5bb97401a13ac930aa810c0c6f3a0855bb6888
  starting
  mariadb service is starting, waiting 2 seconds before checking again.
  /usr/bin/docker inspect --format="{{if .Config.Healthcheck}}{{print .State.Health.Status}}{{end}}" 50f5710f2a561543de7646211a5bb97401a13ac930aa810c0c6f3a0855bb6888
  starting
  mariadb service is starting, waiting 4 seconds before checking again.
  /usr/bin/docker inspect --format="{{if .Config.Healthcheck}}{{print .State.Health.Status}}{{end}}" 50f5710f2a561543de7646211a5bb97401a13ac930aa810c0c6f3a0855bb6888
  unhealthy
Service container mariadb failed.
  /usr/bin/docker logs --details 50f5710f2a561543de7646211a5bb97401a13ac930aa810c0c6f3a0855bb6888
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.1.2-MariaDB-1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 9bc25d98209df6810f7a7d5e7dd3ae677a313ab5 as process 100
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using transactional memory
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=4096 bytes)
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=46157
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 46157; transaction id 14
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
  Warning: 15  6:01:29 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@50f5710f2a56' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
  Warning: 15  6:01:29 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@50f5710f2a56' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
   2023-10-15  6:01:29 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
   Version: '11.1.2-MariaDB-1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  mariadb.org binary distribution
   ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 25: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
   2023-10-15 06:01:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
   2023-10-15 06:01:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
   2023-10-15 06:01:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
   2023-10-15 06:01:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
   
   
   PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !
   To do so, start the server, then issue the following command:
   
   '/usr/bin/mariadb-secure-installation'
   
   which will also give you the option of removing the test
   databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
   strongly recommended for production servers.
   
   See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at https://mariadb.com/kb
   
   Please report any problems at https://mariadb.org/jira
   
   The latest information about MariaDB is available at https://mariadb.org/.
   
   Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
   https://mariadb.org/get-involved/
   
   2023-10-15 06:01:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
   2023-10-15 06:01:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
   2023-10-15 06:01:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
   2023-10-15 06:01:30+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
   2023-10-15 06:01:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database db
   2023-10-15 06:01:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user root
   2023-10-15 06:01:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user root access to schema db
   2023-10-15 06:01:31+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Securing system users (equivalent to running mysql_secure_installation)
  Error: Failed to initialize container mariadb:latest
Error: One or more containers failed to start.
```

My password is correct. I tried to change the database variables in workflow, but it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like the heath check retries are exhausted before the container is fully initialized and that causes this failure. Adjust the health check i.e. increase the number of tries with `--health-retries` to a bigger value and wait for it to start.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work on my workflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker mysql ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086162/docker-mysql-error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-root)

Comment: Verified that this occurs because `root` user already exists hence the above duplicate. Used this [workflow](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxtUl1rwjAUfe+vuPQ9opNtkNFBpcL2MDpah4+Sptma2SZd7q2y/fqlalWwBC5JzrkfOSdGNIpDI5wWZbFB5XZaKgwCazjsrdt+1na/KTW2gmQVBN+2QB4ASN1HANcZZD23KzpDHasFKaTggA3FjkwYmgxHAN2Ir0tzfsod0NY6wgsZgEE4n08feB/C870yu2vSW5y9xslik8SreBHnSw5lMQJ/5MvMD+1HHAHf4zxfp1nCoRWIXoVyhJSl6eqK6aylG7ZtSVuDHJ7Z9TtYpURNFZNNGYXHvayU3E6w8qC0xihJfqeNsd4UbTRpUes/VYZjZbQhr7Soo9kUx3DSjbIdRfejqFPktMJofjKNVHtWnYE5fI+8sntIFpd8b7v37Rd/6r6QRYLZ3eNk6tcMWNfLCqwd5ACmIMxf0jUMpuRPYfAPhUCvFQ==) to verify.

Comment: Here's the test workflow run: https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/6587410084/job/17897639567