# Why can't I alter my user password in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to expire a user 'JohnDoe' password. I executed the alter statement below:

```
ALTER USER 'JohnDoe'@'mysql' PASSWORD EXPIRE;
```

And the error message:

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'JohnDoe'@'mysql'
```

Is it a syntax error or something else? And how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it user@localhost ?

Comment: A syntax error would tell you it was a syntax error. So it's not that. Are you sure you specified the user details correctly? As the comment above notes, it's pretty unusual to call your server `mysql`, although I suppose you might have done.

Comment: @m.qayyum same error when I change to localhost. ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'JohnDoe'@'localhost'

Comment: @ADyson ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'JohnDoe'@'localhost'

Comment: The user alering this does have permissions to do so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost

Comment: @m.qayyum yup, it is the root user and have alter privilege

Comment: We didn't say that localhost was definitely correct, just that you should go away and check the correct hostname to specify

Comment: ahh, my local host name is "root@localhost", thanks for the help!

Comment: To be precise, in that example root is the username, and localhost is the host. In Mysql a user's access is defined by both. You can read more about the concepts online if you search

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are specifying the user incorrectly. I can recreate your error message if I use the wrong user name or host name. To check the user name and host you could try a query to find the user by name:

```
select * from mysql.user where `User` = 'JohnDoe';
```

Then when you have confirmed the user name and host from that table you can use the correct name and host and the statement should work.

```
ALTER USER 'User'@'Host' PASSWORD EXPIRE;
```