# mysql> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, windows-10

Initially I tried to setup a connection between MySQL and Node.JS and got error *ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE*, which I tried to fix by issuing `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'` and flushing privileges as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server). But after that I got another error *ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'*, which I tried to solve by dropping and creating new user, among other steps as suggested on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost).

However, now I am unable to create any database at all, getting *ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'test'*. I login successfully to MySQL command line client with the password that I setup during the installation but it seems I am not allowed to perform any operation there. How could I restore my privileges to create databases on MySQL v 8.0 on Windows 10?

Here is some other output which I get after issuing certain commands:

```
mysql> select user(), current_user;
+----------------+----------------+
| user()         | current_user   |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> CREATE DATABASE test;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'test'
mysql> mysql -u root -p;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -p' at line 1
mysql>
```