# ERROR 1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed

Tags: mysql

ّI was creating a db in mysql and ran commands

```
CREATE USER 'eco_db'@'localhost';


GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON eco_db.* To 'eco_db'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'eco_db@1';
```

and this is my error message:

```
#1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed for 'eco_db'@'localhost'
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555328/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-jacklocalhost

Comment: Do not try to imagine your own syntax, server won't accept it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html